# What are the main mathematical approaches to materials modeling?

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-mechanics, molecular-modeling, mathematical-modeling

What are the main mathematical approaches to materials modeling? This can include both analytical (closed-form) and numerical techniques.

Comment: Same comment as your other post. This runs the risk of turning into an ever changing long list. You want to narrow this down to a narrower, more specific subset of materials modelling. For example, mathematical techniques used in modeling surface binding with molecular mechanics or charge transfer with DFT or something more of specific interest to you.

Comment: For the most part I agree with @Tyberius on this one. I do note that it is possible for questions like these to be very successful though: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-the-models-of-quantum-computation. So perhaps this question can be saved with a bit more detail.

Comment: Here is another example of a great "list" answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1524/2293

Comment: Perhaps you could narrow down the scope of the question to a specific length & time scale (e.g. ab-initio techniques, classical molecular dynamics, or continuum-based approaches, etc.) or to a specific domain (e.g. batteries, catalysts, structural alloys, electronic materials, etc.)